# Send Different Token Value For Deployer (Airdrop/Whitelist With Merkletree)

Tags: solidity, javascript, airdrop

At script folder,
I wrote addreses and amounts like this:

```
const walletAddresses = [
    ["0xC13F4eEa4149A063f6483b94163C9d72........", "2000000000000000000"],
    ["0xB532401cC59732e510d9F10d84EC327D........", "3000000000000000000"],
    ["0xDaBA4f99Df689F407Bea770a92a24294........", "4000000000000000000"]
  ]
```

I used merkle tree for airdrop like this:

```
const leaves = walletAddresses.map(x => KECCAK256(["address", "uint256"], x), "\n");
const tree = new MerkleTree(leaves, KECCAK256, { sortPairs: true })
```

Fınally ı want to send token for deployer. And for this I wrote:

```
distributor = await MerkleDistributor.deploy(
    token.address,
    tree.getHexRoot(),
    BigNumber.from(?????????)     
  );
```

What should I write in the place with the question mark so that when the person whose address is in the whitelist deploys her contract, the value near of address is sent to deployer address.

Comment: Did you try a block nomber?

Comment: I dont understand block number. How can I use in there?